# C# Simplificação IF

Tags: c#, condição

Tenho este código, e estive a pesquisar uma forma de simplificá-lo usando um operador ternário, mas não estou a conseguir, pois diz que não posso usar decimal em string:

```
decimal per;
if (nud_qtPedida.Value != 0)
   per = nud_qtFornecida.Value * 100 / nud_qtPedida.Value;
else
  per = 0;
txt_percentagem.Text = per.ToString();
```

Comment: Só tome cuidado para não abusar do uso de operadores ternários, pois eles, em algumas circunstâncias dificultam a leitura e manutenção do código. Eu não vejo problema no código da pergunta que necessite ser colocado em um `If` ternário.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes utilizar um operador ternário para fazer a validação da nud_qtPedida.

- Podes começar por fazer assim:

  ```
  decimal per=nud_qtPedida.Value !=0 ? nud_qtFornecida.Value * 100 / nud_qtPedida.Value:0;
  txt_percentagem.Text = per.ToString();
  ```
- Depois podes fazer tudo numa só linha se perceberes:

  ```
  txt_percentagem.Text = (nud_qtPedida.Value !=0 ? nud_qtFornecida.Value * 100 / nud_qtPedida.Value:0).ToString();
  ```

## Operador Ternário

O operador ternário funciona assim: `Condição ? valor_se_verdadeiro : valor_se_falso`;

Comment: Acho que o mais correto seria algo como `Condição ? valor_se_verdadeiro : valor_se_falso`. Valor afirmativo e negativo fica meio sem sentido.

Comment: Tens razão, vou já alterar, obrigado